# Manipulate table background colour based on SQL with parameter was table value

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am trying to develop my website. There is a table that I made in as a button. I get the value of the button with JavaScript like this:

```
<script>
    function setvalue(values) {
        document.getElementById('posisi').value = values;
    }
</script>
```

HTML of my table:

```
<table width="1023" height="248" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" scope="col">A1</th>
    <th colspan="2" scope="col">A2</th>
    <th colspan="2" scope="col">A3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><div align="center"><input type="button" onclick="popup_window_show('#sample', { pos : 'tag-right-down',   parent : this, width : '270px' });setvalue(this.value);" value="A1.4" /></td>
    <td><div align="center"><input type="button" onclick="popup_window_show('#sample', { pos : 'tag-right-down',   parent : this, width : '270px' });setvalue(this.value);" value="A1.8" /></td>
    <td><div align="center"><input type="button" onclick="popup_window_show('#sample', { pos : 'tag-right-down',   parent : this, width : '270px' });setvalue(this.value);" value="A2.4" /></td>
    <td><div align="center"><input type="button" onclick="popup_window_show('#sample', { pos : 'tag-right-down',   parent : this, width : '270px' });setvalue(this.value);" value="A2.8" /></td>
    <td><div align="center"><input type="button" onclick="popup_window_show('#sample', { pos : 'tag-right-down',   parent : this, width : '270px' });setvalue(this.value);" value="A3.4" /></td>
    <td><div align="center"><input type="button" onclick="popup_window_show('#sample', { pos : 'tag-right-down',   parent : this, width : '270px' });setvalue(this.value);" value="A3.8" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I try to manipulate background colour with this JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var htmlobjek;
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     var pid = "document.getElementById('posisi').value = values";
    $.ajax({
        url: "cek.php",
        data: "pid="+posisi,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
```

My algorithm when my SQL success in cek.php I will call back and display in current page to manipulate the table background colour.

In cek.php my SQL like this:

```
SELECT ..
FROM..
WHERE posisi='S_POST[posisi]'
```

I will count the result (use this `mssql_num_row(sql)`). If the result has a value, the background colour of the table will be red. If not, it will be green. This is what makes me confused. Any idea for my website? I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: I have a little trouble figuring out what you mean, do you want your rows odd-even colored ?

Comment: var pid = "document.getElementById('posisi').value = values";
should be 
`var pid = document.getElementById('posisi').value`

Comment: @NiekvanderSteen no that just simple methode. i want coloring my table according value of my sql in cek.php. if value true (mean Just 1 result) so the table colour is red if empty the colour is green

Comment: what exactly isn't working?

Comment: @mattl how to figure out the value from my sql in cek.php and and make that to manipulate ech table background colour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ajaxCall = $.ajax({
    url: "cek.php",
    type:'POST',
    data: {"data": i},
    cache: false,
}).done( function (data) {
    $("#cek").val(data);
}).fail( function () {
    alert('I can not send ajax here');
});

// Now anywhere in your script:
ajaxCall.done( function (data) {
    var k = $("#cek").val();
    // You can now even do:
    // var k = data;
    if(k == "0"){
        $(".data").css("background-color", "#00CC00");//green
    }
    else {
        $(".data").css("background-color", "#FF0000");//red
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use success function like this...

```
 success: function() 
{

   if(rsp.success)
   {
```

set `rsp` as background colour here
       }

```
 }
```

Comment: that's not what i mean.... if something like that maybe i wouldn't ask here. the problem is how to figure out value from my sql and make that value as variable to change backgroud table. if true the background color is red if false will green

Comment: when u get something from query in cek.php , use return for that that will get into the success function....as far as i knw ur problm.

Comment: ya.. tq i know that. i try to make a dynamic table that can change background colour automaticly based on num result from that query. so from query there is condition to make variance value. if num result is 0 so the backgroud colour of table will green. else if num of sql result >=1 the backgroud colour will red. this colour change automaticly. i said before that table content i make as button to call popup form. so when user fill the form, num of result       of sql result >= 1 n table backgroud colour automaticly change to red after user click save button. if delete will green